# openSUSE 11.4 doesn't wake up from suspend to ram, sometimes doesn't logout

Tags: opensuse, nvidia, suspend

I have openSUSE 11.4 on a vaio S series laptop, using KDE, and it is nearly up-to-date. Everything was fine but after an update (whose details I can't remember), these problems appeared:

- Nearly every time I suspend to ram, it doesn't wake up.
- Sometimes when I'm working in KDE, the mouse doesn't do anything. It just moves around but its clicks don't have any effect. I have to logout and login again to resolve that problem.

I think that these two problems are the same. Also, I'm using nvidia proprietary driver version **275.21-7.1**.

What should I do to debug this? What's your opinion about downgrading nvidia driver?

Answer (score 0):

The whole mouse and suspend thing kind of makes me think X is buggy.

Check `/var/log/zypp/history`, that should be the location of zypper's history log file. That will tell you what you've recently installed/updated.

Comment: i've checked the file, here you can see some part of it: [link](http://pastebin.com/GdmYqjyb). my xorg version is 7.6-43.44.1, but i haven't found anything on web regarding to any problem with this version. do you think downgrading is the solution? i say this because i had that problem with mouse from the first install. thanx ;-)

Comment: You could give a downgrade a try, if that's worked in the past. But I don't think that's the problem.  If you can live with the possibility of losing some of your currently installed software, you can try `sudo zypper dist-upgrade`, which will sync all your packages to match the official repositories.

Comment: when i enter that command, it shows me [this list](http://pastebin.com/jTiQ2kFJ), and it doesn't do anything with xorg. so what should i do? is there any alternative version of xorg that i could use? also i didn't find any option regarding downgrading in zypper except `dist-upgrade`. do i have to download xorg from it's own website and compile it by myself?

Comment: There aren't any alternate versions that I know of. But I meant downgrading the version of your driver, not X. Also, there might be differences between the free and non-free versions of the driver which might be causing the issues.